# SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, liferay

I have a custom portlet deployed at our portal which has the functionality of file attachment. When I am trying to submit data after attaching the file in that portlet, I get the following error in Internet Explorer 9 -

SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

everything.jsp?browserId=ie&themeId=classic&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&minifierBundleId=javascript.everything.files&languageId=en_US&b=6120&t=1389913542000, line 38262 character 4

Comment: There are many similar questions but none has a solution to my problem.